# how to insert a new integer index ipython pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, ipython

I made value count dataframe from another dataframe
for example

```
                 freq
     0            2
     0.33333      10
     1.66667      13
```

automatically, its indexs are 0, 0.3333, 1.66667 
and the indexs can be variable 
because I intend to make many dataframes based on a specific value

how can I insert a integer index?

like

```
                  freq
0   0              2
1   0.33333        10
2   1.66667        13
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The result you get back from `values_count` is a series, and to set a generic 1 ... n index, you can use `reset_index`:

```
In [4]: s = pd.Series([0,0.3,0.3,1.6])

In [5]: s.value_counts()
Out[5]:
0.3    2
1.6    1
0.0    1
dtype: int64

In [9]: s.value_counts().reset_index(name='freq')
Out[9]:
   index  freq
0    0.3     2
1    1.6     1
2    0.0     1
```

Comment: why I got 'reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'' message??

Comment: Probably because you have an older version of pandas. You can leave that out, and rename the columns afterwards.